# Prove that a function is strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

I have the following function
$$
f(x)= x\left (1 + \displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^M \  \frac{p}{1 + D_{j}\cdot x}}  \right)- t.
$$

$x$ is the only variable (the others are positive constants). We have been asked to show two things:

1. Function is positive for some large values of $x$.
2. Function is strictly increasing for positive $x$.

For (1) I can just use a few values to prove it. For the second part, I'm thinking of taking the derivative of this function and proving that it will always be positive. I got the derivative and said that for very large values of $x$ (as $x\to\infty$), the derivative will converge to $1$. Thus it will be strictly increasing. Just hoping someone can help me confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got the derivative and said that for very large values of $x$ (as $x\to\infty$), the derivative will converge to $1$

All that this proves is that $f(x)$ is increasing *for sufficiently large $x$*. Since you were asked to prove that $f(x)$ increases at *all positive* values of $x$, it's not enough.

Here's a hint: what's the derivative of $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+ k x}$, where $k$ is a constant? Can you find a simplified expression? What can you say about its sign?

Comment: Thank you for this. The thing you've given me would be 1/(1+kx)^2, which is always positive. Since my function is a positive value multiplied to this, we know this is always positive. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it

For 1 you just take $x>t$.

2 boils down to showing that
$$
x\left (1 + \displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^M \  \frac{p}{1 + D_{j}*x}}  \right)<y\left (1 + \displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^M \  \frac{p}{1 + D_{j}*y}}  \right)
$$
when $0<x<y$. To show this, is sufficient to show that
$$
\frac{x}{1 + D_{j}*x}<\frac{y}{1 + D_{j}*y}
$$

Rearranging the terms, we have $x+D_j*xy<y+D_j*xy\iff x<y.$